# What graphical launcher program can I use?

Tags: xorg, x11, xming

I have the following setup:

I am running Ubuntu on VirtualBox in a Windows Environment. I am using Xming launcher to start xterm from Ubuntu as a client from where I can launch other graphical programs.

However, starting multiple programs from xterm with `&` means that the xterm window receives the output from the other applications and becomes very cluttered.

Is there some other program I can run in the Ubuntu system that acts as a graphical launcher/tray for other apps?

Answer (score 1):

Rather then try and get Xming working reliably I would use [VirtualBox's Seamless Mode instead](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/virtualboxs-seamless-mode-combine-operating-systems-desktop/). Seamless mode lets you take applications that are running inside your VirtualBox VM and collapse all of the OS GUI around the app so that the application running inside the VM shows up all by itself.

A screenshot says it better than I can:

[image: ss of seamless]

Above you can see a game of Solitaire in a Windows VirtualBox VM running along side Solitaire on the host Ubuntu box.

Here's a [video that shows it in action](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxVO-ogIiOo) as well.